# What determines the applicative log file location in Apache/Django?

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

([Cross posted to Server Fault some time ago](https://serverfault.com/questions/251254/what-determines-the-applicative-log-file-location-in-apache-django))

I have a django app running on Apache/ubuntu, and I have evidently misconfigured it.
When I start apache, I'm getting this error in the apache log:

```
 ...
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/osqa/sites/log/django.osqa.log'
```

Now, my site is supposed to be running in 'home/osqa/sites/foobar/'. Why is django/apache looking for a log file in a folder **above** that folder? Where is this configured? How to resolve/analyze?

Comment: That sounds like django 1.3 logging, which would be configured in settings.py. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Josh - I don't see anything related in settings.py. What should I look for? How do I determine django version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines in your httpd.conf file is what is causing your problem:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/beta-meta-d3c.access.log common
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/beta-meta-d3c.error.log
```

This logging is set up for apache as a whole, not just your application which is set up in a subdirectory within apache.

`${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` should evaluate to `/home/osqa/sites/log/`. Fully expanded with your log names it will be:

```
/home/osqa/sites/log/beta-meta-d3c.access.log
```

Which is exactly what it is telling you. Either create that directory and make it writeable, or change your httpd conf to append the name of your application to the logging path directive. I'd probably not change the path though, as other applications might want to log also, but not to your directory.

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that it's something in your apache2 config. Go to sites-available/your-site.com.conf, and look in its file. Perhaps you'll find that it is logging things?

Comment: I don't see what it can be. Here is my "sites-availble/my-site" (without .conf suffix, if that matter). https://gist.github.com/890269